center bar in dynamic number of columns
I am trying to make a clustered column chart where in if the values in the category are positive and negative, they are going to be stacked in one column but if the values in the category are both positive or both negatives then they must be displayed side by side instead of stacked.
However, the column positioning is not always centered. Setting a definite offset will work but if the number of columns change then it will not be centered again.

You mean like this?

{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega/v5.json",
  "width": 700,
  "height": 370,
  "autosize": {"type": "fit", "contains": "padding"},
  "padding": {"bottom": 2, "right": 9, "left": 5},
  "config": {
    "axis": {
      "labelFont": "HelveticaNeueLTW01-55Roman",
      "titleFont": "HelveticaNeueLTW01-55Roman"
    }
  },
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "income_and_expenses",
      "values": [
        {"label": "2012", "value1": 208.91, "value2": 500},
        {"label": "2013", "value1": 115.61, "value2": -458.76},
        {"label": "2014", "value1": 135.7, "value2": -335.23},
        {"label": "2015", "value1": 148.75, "value2": -83.61},
        {"label": "2016", "value1": 152.57, "value2": 0.36},
        {"label": "2017", "value1": 198.23, "value2": 0.29},
        {"label": "2018", "value1": 911.81, "value2": 0.58},
        {"label": "2019", "value1": 342.44, "value2": 14.48},
        {"label": "2020", "value1": 664.46, "value2": 11.51}
      ],
      "transform": [
        {"type": "formula", "expr": "split(datum.label, ' ')", "as": "label"}
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "parsed",
      "source": ["income_and_expenses"],
      "transform": [
        {
          "type": "aggregate",
          "fields": ["value1", "value1", "value2", "value2"],
          "ops": ["min", "max", "min", "max"],
          "as": ["min_value1", "max_value1", "min_value2", "max_value2"]
        },
        {
          "type": "formula",
          "expr": "datum.max_value1 > datum.max_value2 ? abs(datum.max_value1) : abs(datum.max_value2)",
          "as": "mergedMax"
        },
        {
          "type": "formula",
          "expr": "datum.min_value1 < datum.min_value2 ? abs(datum.min_value1) : abs(datum.min_value2)",
          "as": "mergedMin"
        },
        {
          "type": "formula",
          "expr": "datum.mergedMax > datum.mergedMin ? datum.mergedMax : datum.mergedMin",
          "as": "max"
        },
        {"type": "formula", "expr": "-(datum.max)", "as": "min"}
      ]
    }
  ],
  "scales": [
    {
      "name": "x",
      "type": "band",
      "range": "width",
      "domain": {"data": "income_and_expenses", "field": "label"}
    },
    {
      "name": "y",
      "type": "linear",
      "range": "height",
      "nice": true,
      "zero": true,
      "domain": {"data": "parsed", "field": "limit"},
      "domainMin": {"signal": "pluck(data('parsed'), 'min')"},
      "domainMax": {"signal": "pluck(data('parsed'), 'max')"}
    }
  ],
  "axes": [
    {
      "orient": "bottom",
      "scale": "x",
      "zindex": 1,
      "labelFontSize": 14,
      "labelColor": "#85868C",
      "labelAlign": "center",
      "labelLineHeight": 19.6,
      "labelFontWeight": "normal",
      "labelPadding": 8,
      "labelOpacity": 1,
      "domain": false,
      "domainColor": "#e5e5e5",
      "domainWidth": 1,
      "ticks": false,
      "grid": true
    },
    {
      "orient": "left",
      "scale": "y",
      "zindex": 0,
      "labelFontSize": 14,
      "labelColor": "#85868C",
      "labelLineHeight": 19.6,
      "labelFontWeight": "normal",
      "labelPadding": 8,
      "labelOpacity": 1,
      "domain": false,
      "domainColor": "#e5e5e5",
      "grid": true,
      "gridOpacity": 0.5,
      "ticks": false,
      "tickCount": 4,
      "gridDash": {"signal": "datum.value == 0 ? [] : [4,4]"},
      "encode": {
        "labels": {
          "update": {
            "text": {
              "signal": "if(abs(datum.value) >= 1e9, format(datum.value/1e9, '$,.1~f') + 'B', if(abs(datum.value) >= 1e6, format(datum.value/1e6, '$,.1~f') + 'M', if(abs(datum.value) >= 1e3, format(datum.value/1e3, '$,.1~f') + 'K', format(datum.value, '$,.2~f'))))"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "marks": [
    {
      "name": "income",
      "type": "rect",
      "from": {"data": "income_and_expenses"},
      "encode": {
        "enter": {
          "xc": {
            "scale": "x",
            "field": "label",
            "band": 0.5,
            "offset": {
              "signal": "datum.value1 > 0 && datum.value2 > 0  || datum.value1 < 0 && datum.value2 < 0 ? -8 : 0"
            }
          },
          "width": {"value": 16},
          "y": {"scale": "y", "field": "value1"},
          "y2": {"scale": "y", "value": 0},
          "fill": {"value": "#68abf2"},
          "cornerRadiusTopLeft": {"signal": "datum.value1 > 0 ? '2' : '0'"},
          "cornerRadiusTopRight": {"signal": "datum.value1 > 0 ? '2' : '0'"},
          "cornerRadiusBottomLeft": {"signal": "datum.value1 > 0 ? '0' : '2'"},
          "cornerRadiusBottomRight": {"signal": "datum.value1 > 0 ? '0' : '2'"}
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "expenses",
      "type": "rect",
      "from": {"data": "income_and_expenses"},
      "encode": {
        "enter": {
          "x": {
            "scale": "x",
            "field": "label",
            "band": 0.5,
            "offset": {
              "signal": "datum.value1 > 0 && datum.value2 > 0  || datum.value1 < 0 && datum.value2 < 0 ? 0 : -8"
            }
          },
          "width": {"value": 16},
          "y": {"scale": "y", "field": "value2"},
          "y2": {"scale": "y", "value": 0},
          "fill": {"value": "#f7615c"},
          "cornerRadiusTopLeft": {"signal": "datum.value2 > 0 ? '2' : '0'"},
          "cornerRadiusTopRight": {"signal": "datum.value2 > 0 ? '2' : '0'"},
          "cornerRadiusBottomLeft": {"signal": "datum.value2 > 0 ? '0' : '2'"},
          "cornerRadiusBottomRight": {"signal": "datum.value2 > 0 ? '0' : '2'"}
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}


Amazing thanks @davidebacci :) Yes, that's what I'm going for except that I need a gap spacing between the bars of value1 and value2 when they are positioned side by side with each other (e.g. both positive and both negative). Do you think we can have a gap between them while maintaing the center position?

Yes, just change your offset calculation to accommodate a gap size.
